# SQL Server - Showing total number of COUNT within a Category

Tags: sql-server

I have a SELECT statement which sorts reviews depending on their year and category. It shows the data correctly but what can I possibly do in order for it to show the total number of reviews of the year, and the total number of reviews in all.

```
SELECT PRH.PRHYear AS 'Year',
   C.CategoryName AS 'Category',
   COUNT(*) AS 'Reviews'
FROM ProductRankingHistory PRH
 RIGHT JOIN
 Review R
 ON PRH.PRHProduct = R.ProductID
 RIGHT JOIN
 Product P
 ON R.ProductID = P.ProductID
 RIGHT JOIN
 Category C
 ON P.CategoryID = C.CategoryID
WHERE R.ProductID = P.ProductID AND
  P.CategoryID = C.CategoryID AND
  C.CategoryID = PRH.PRHCategory
GROUP BY PRH.PRHYear, C.CategoryName
ORDER BY PRHYear ASC
```

Comment: will have to be a separate statement otherwise you will them repeating per category

Comment: Is it possible to modify this statement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Total number of reviews in a year can be calculated by expression `count(*) over (partition by year)`. You can put it directly in `ORDER BY` clause

```
SELECT PRH.PRHYear AS 'Year',
   C.CategoryName AS 'Category',
   COUNT(*) AS 'Reviews'
FROM ProductRankingHistory PRH
 RIGHT JOIN
 Review R
 ON PRH.PRHProduct = R.ProductID
 RIGHT JOIN
 Product P
 ON R.ProductID = P.ProductID
 RIGHT JOIN
 Category C
 ON P.CategoryID = C.CategoryID
WHERE R.ProductID = P.ProductID AND
  P.CategoryID = C.CategoryID AND
  C.CategoryID = PRH.PRHCategory
GROUP BY PRH.PRHYear, C.CategoryName
ORDER BY PRHYear ASC, count(*) over (partition by year)
```